# How to annotate Django ORM queryset to calculate date difference excluding weekends?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model 'Order' with two datetime fields 'received_at' and 'delivered_at'. now I need to annotate the queryset to add a field 'delivery_duration' that will hold dates count between received_at and delivered_at, excluding weekends (saturday and sunday).

so, if received_at monday and delivered_at same day (monday), the delivery_duration count will be 0.
if received_at monday and delivered_at next wednesday, the delivery_duration count will be 2.
if received_at friday and delivered_at monday, count will be 1.
if received_at friday and delivered_at sunday, count will be 0.
if received_at saturday and delivered_at sunday, count will be 0.

I could achieve dates count with this code:

```
orders = Order.objects.all().annotate(
  delivery_duration = ExpressionWrapper(
    Func(TruncDate('delivered_at') - TruncDate('received_at'),
         function='EXTRACT',
         template='%(function)s(DAY FROM %(expressions)s)'),
         output_field=IntegerField())))
```

this returns the date counts between 'delivered_at' and 'recieved_at' but including weekends. I need to exlude the weekends (staturday, sunday) from count if that is between the range.